# How to iterate through a paginated api from Laravel query on ajax result?

Tags: laravel

I have laravel api paginated as below.

```
    $mymodels = MyModel::paginate(10);
    return response()->json($mymodels);
```

And this is my ajax result management.

```
   data.forEach(function (res,index) {
            html += `<tr > 
                <td> ${res.field1}</td>                                            
                <td> ${res.field2}</td>                               
            </tr>`
        });
```

Problem is that it only loop the first page not all pages which I need all of them instead. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of using pagination is to fetch records from database one page full at a time limited by the value passed to the `paginate()`. Hence it will only show one page full in your case 10 records at a time. If you want to see/fetch the next set of 10 records i.e. from 11-20 you will have to make an ajax request for the next page to the server.  If you want all records at once don't use pagination

Comment: Dear Donkarnash, thanks for info, but my response already show all pages.

Comment: if you want to show all pages why use paginate?

Comment: Dear  Muhammad Dyas Yaskur, thanks. May be my misunderstood.